# .htaccess how to handle dynamic sub-domain redirect to https and no sub-domain to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have my htaccess file gitignored and while upgrading to Laravel 5.2 I deleted the old one on the server. I spent hours piecing it together and now I'm struggling to recreate it.

I need anything like

```
http://domain.com
```

or

```
https://domain.com
```

to goto

```
https://www.domain.com
```

and all other wildcard sub-domains such as:

```
http://myname.domain.com
```

to goto

```
https://myname.domain.com
```

So far I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect subdomains and main domain to HTTPS, you can use:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

#--Redirect subdomain to https--#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R,L]

#--Redirect maindomain to https --#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R,L]
#--Redirect non-www to www on SSL--#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Change `R` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect is working fine.

Comment: Looks pretty good but it will not redirect ```https://domain.com``` to ```https://www.domain.com``` which I realize was not in my original question, updating it now. Thank you.

Comment: I think the periods `.` in the first conditions for each rule need escaping.

Comment: Hey Starkeen, I tested the latest code and it will not redirect ```https://domain.com``` to ```https://www.domain.com```.